# Classification of Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have to find the Order, Dimension and Degree of the following Difference Equations and have to classify them according to their linearity/nonlinearity, homogenity and Autonomous/NonAutonomous nature. Help!!

[image]

Comment: Math StackExchange is not your homework problem solving service

Comment: I said help. I didnt ask you to solve. Atleast provide something for reference or dont bother to comment